# Listing within tcolorbox: how to adjust width to the natural listing width?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I would like to create a `tcolorbox` whose width is computed based on the longest line I have in listed code. I know it is possible to adjust the width with respect to the title. Is it also possible to adjust it based on the content?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage {usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
      arc=7pt,
      outer arc=7pt,
      top=1mm,
      bottom=1mm,
      left=1mm,
      right=1mm,
      boxrule=0.6pt,
      colback=yellow!5,
      colframe=yellow!50!black,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      listing only,
}
    int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep) {
      printf("Hello, World\n");
      return 0;
    }
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply add the option `hbox`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage {usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
      arc=7pt,
      outer arc=7pt,
      top=1mm,
      bottom=1mm,
      left=1mm,
      right=1mm,
      boxrule=0.6pt,
      colback=yellow!5,
      colframe=yellow!50!black,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      listing only,
      hbox
}
    int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep) {
      printf("Hello, World\n");
      return 0;
    }
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, if you want to have the following result

[image]

you have to remove the leading spaces in the lines

```
    int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep) {
      printf("Hello, World\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

being the contents of the listing verbatim contents.